# How Do I Manage Data Connection From Within A Class Library in a Solution With Both Website and Form Apps?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, data-binding

This is a common problem for me.  I have a solution that contains a Form App or two, a couple of websites(Intranet, External site kinda thing) and a class library where I want to store my data objects to be shared among the other project mentioned.

Normally, I'd have my connection strings stored in web.config and app.config files.  However, with the class library, this isn't really possible.  Not without passing in configuration information each time I want to access data.  I'd prefer not to do that.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your connection strings in the web.config and the app.config of the referencing applications the Dll's will read them fine. If you want them shared you can put them in a machine config. You could also put them in a [separate file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx) and reference them from each web and app config.

Comment: Hmm, okay.  One of my projects is a class library for my NUnit tests.  Where do I manage the database configuration in this scenario?  I have an app.config, do I use that?  How do I get those values?